# To infinity... and beyond?

Tags: focus

In the old days when I wanted to take pictures of distant objects, like landscapes, with my 35mm OM-2 I would just move the focus all the end: infinity. Now, however, my lenses focus *past* infinity. How can you focus past infinity? I don't get that. Not only is it really inconvenient, but I would think scientifically impossible. What's going on with this?

Comment: Could you explain why you think this is "scientifically impossible"? A lens "just" bends light, all focusing past infinity means is that it is bending it less than it needs to in order to make parallel rays converge.

Comment: @RomeoNinov That post does not specifically address focus PAST infinity. It is about infinity focus, not focus past infinity.

Comment: Check here, you will see a lot of Q/A: https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some lenses focus past infinity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40995/why-do-some-lenses-focus-past-infinity) [One of the comments](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40995/why-do-some-lenses-focus-past-infinity#comment68560_40995) even has the same joke :)

Comment: [Why am I allowed to turn my focusing ring beyond infinity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2408) | [Why do some lenses focus past infinity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40995) | [What does focusing past infinity look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105755)

Comment: I think that's plenty of duplicate suggestions now, closing this :)

Answer (score -1):

In the old days all our lenses had an "infinity stop". Nowadays, many lenses allow a setting that is beyond infinity. This gives the lens greater flexibility to be fitted on different cameras with different adapters. In other words, on some setups, the distance from the rear glass lens element to sensitive surface (back-focus) might be different. We are talking about differences of the distance between mounting flange and sensitive surface for different camera brands.

Comment: Are you able to provide any evidence at all to support this statement? Certainly none of the first party manufacturers have an interest in making their lenses useable on different brands.

Comment: @ Philip Kendall - No evidence whatsoever - just looking at other posts that complain that the lens they bought does not have an infinity stop. I have been wrong more that 1000 times this probably is 1001.